# How to show 2 tables data in 1 view using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

There is two tables (one is Users and second is Branches). I want to show the Branch with its Branch Admin Name.And the branch Admin info is save in users table. There is an error When i am trying to show the data of Two table in one view. Tell me How i manage this issue.

View:

```
<div class="branches col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control search" placeholder="Search">

    <div class="spaces"></div>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                BranchName
            </th>
            <th>
                BranchAdmin
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th>
                Contact
            </th>
            <th>
                Location
            </th>
            <th>
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($branch as $brnch)
            <tr class="branchies-row">
                <td>
                    {{$brnch->branch_name}}
                </td>
                @foreach($user as $users)
                    <td>
                        {{$users->name}}
                    </td>
                @endforeach
                <td>
                    {{$brnch->email}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$brnch->contact}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$brnch->address}}
                </td>


                <td>
                    <a data-id="{{$brnch->id}}" class="delete-branch">Delete</a> /
                    <a href="/branch/edit/{{$brnch->id}}">Edit </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function getBranchinfo(){
    $user = User::where('type', '=', 'BranchAdmin');
    $branch = Branch::all();
    return view('Branch.branchinfo')->with('branch',$branch)->with('user', $user);
}
```

Model:

```
public function branch(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Branch', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: You are getting 2 collections users and branch. You need create relationship with user from branch and get branch and user in one query https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading . What error you have now, you forgot add `->get()` after where statment?

Answer (score 1):

We can use query builder - [Join](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins) - for that :

```
$branches = DB::table('Branches')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'Branches.user_id')
            ->where('users.type', '=', 'BranchAdmin')
            ->get();
```

and this should give you the data you need.

Comment: I'd argue that a bit more elegant solution is to have defined relations between models. In that case manual join is not needed. ORM is already in place, so why not using it.

Comment: @sava To be honest i prefer query builder since it's more efficient and more faster specially when retrieving huge data

Comment: I can not object that :) As you get closer to the database, you get more control over how the data is being fetched, thus the data retrieval can be optimized better.

Comment: @sava and  sometimes i find the relations between the models a little bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the relationship in branch model:

```
public function user(){
return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
```

}

Then in blade file you get branch admin name as:

```
@foreach($branch as $brnch)
        <tr class="branchies-row">
            <td>{{ $brnch->user->branchadmincloumn }}</td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

`branchadmincloumn` is the cloumn name from your users table where your branch admin name is saving. So change `branchadmincloumn` to your desired column name.
Hope it helps..