# how to manage the id's using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

[image]I am join two tables (one is User and the second table is branch) and print the BranchAdmin name with its branch in the single view, the branchAdmin information is save in the User table, but when i perform the edit function on the branch data, it will show an empty page and only show the edit form when users and branch id is match. So how i manage that when i edit the branch it only concern with the branch id not with the company id that is foreign key in the branch?

Branch Controller:

```
public function getBranchinfo(){
    $branch = DB::table('branch')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'branch.user_id')
        ->where('users.type', '=', 'BranchAdmin')
        ->get();
    return view('Branch.branchinfo')->with('branch',$branch);
}
```

BranchDetails View:

```
<div class="branches col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    <input type="text" class="pull-right form-control search" placeholder="Search">

    <div class="spaces"></div>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                id
            </th>
            <th>
                Branch-Name
            </th>
            <th>
                AdminName
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th>
                Contact
            </th>
            <th>
                Location
            </th>
            <th>
                OpenHours
            </th>
            <th>
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($branch as $brnch)
            <tr class="branchies-row">
                <td>
                    {{$brnch->id}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$brnch->branch_name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                     Note->(In this i will take the name of user who is Admin of branch.) like this ($brnch->user_name)
                    {{$brnch->user_id}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$brnch->email}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$brnch->contact}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$brnch->address}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$brnch->open_hours}}
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a data-id="{{$brnch->id}}" class="delete-branch">Delete</a> /
                    <a href="/branch/edit/{{$brnch->id}}">Edit </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Branch Migration:

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('branch', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
        // here you need to define on deleteCascade, when this records delete, this will also
        // delete it's records from other tables that related to this one via a foriegn key.
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('company')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->String('branch_name');
        $table->String('email');
        $table->String('address');
        $table->String('contact');
        $table->String('open_hours');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

User Model:

```
public function branch(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Branch', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to get? Is it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441770/how-to-show-2-tables-data-in-1-view-using-laravel/43449384#43449384?.. I answered this

Comment: See this picture in table the branch->id and user->id(AdminName) of type branchAdmin are same i don't know why ?

Comment: Because you are getting the same id

Comment: Have you seen that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441770/how-to-show-2-tables-data-in-1-view-using-laravel/43449384#43449384?

Comment: How ?But there is two different tables the branch id is different from user id.

Comment: How you get the admin name..I have answered this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441770/how-to-show-2-tables-data-in-1-view-using-laravel/43449384#43449384

Comment: But why, when i edit the branch its not show the form. And only showing the edit form when the id's are matched?

Comment: I am not getting you, what you exactly want? Can you come on chat?

Comment: ok but how we will private chat?

Comment: You are talking about edit form, but from your above code, there's not any form, its just showing data

Comment: And I told you to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441770/how-to-show-2-tables-data-in-1-view-using-laravel/43449384#43449384

Answer (score 1):

i think that the problem is that the two table have a field called id so if you wanna remove the conflict you can just inverse the order of your join so the last id you get from the query is the branch id

```
$branch = DB::table('user')
    ->join('branch', 'branch.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('users.type', '=', 'BranchAdmin')
    ->get();
```

you can add aliases like this

```
$branch = DB::table('user')
->select(DB::raw('brunch.*, brunch.id as branch_id, user.*'))
->join('branch', 'branch.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->where('users.type', '=', 'BranchAdmin')
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks but, tell me that if i also print the Company->Id in the table that are foreign key in Branch, so how i get the last id from the query is the branch id?

Comment: i updated my anwer you can find the second option  using aliases